# Is a little urinary incontinence forgiven?

Tags: taharah

Because sometimes when I take off my clothes I find that a little urine has come out without me realising it.  Do I have to change my underwear for every prayer? Or i should just put tissue May Allaah reward you with good.

Comment: If its less than a dirham in size, which it sounds to be, then it is just Sunnah to clean. Remember Allah does not intend hardship with purification. It is likely Shaitanic whispers giving you doubts about purity. You can help get rid of these whispers by splashing water on the affected area, then you can't tell what is water and what is urine and you can just ignore it in your mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that some drops of urine have come out, then you have to clean yourself again and repeat your wudoo’ for each prayer,

> and you have to wash off whatever urine has got onto your clothes.

[here](https://islamqa.info/en/1198)

```
we come to the most important what if the urine has come out the 
time of prayer during or before prayer and 
you can not hold it more than enough time to do prayer even if you 
did wudoo (ablution) again it will come out.
```

> you do only one time wudoo(ablution) then you should wrap it with
>   extra cloth to ensure it does not go to underwear

[here](https://islamqa.info/en/39494)

Salaamun'alaykum. If as the brother asks, without him '... being aware of it.' then may I say that since he was not aware as at the time he prayed, then the prayer remains VALID.

والله اعلم (And Allaah knows best.)

Comment: But brother this is so hard especially if I am at public places or outdoors.

Comment: you should ask doctor about the reason and If he can give you medicine it's OK but if no cure cover the head of your penis with any thing [example](https://www.jiftip.com/) and reomve it after you pray or when you are at home

Comment: i do not understand which quote is from  which link, and what means "code" style quote here